# Why am I receiving a None response for a class that exists when web scraping a table with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner with Python and Beautiful Soup, any help would be much appreciated. I am receiving a None response when calling a table by the class name (which exists). See below code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

source = requests.get(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217').text
soup = bs(source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_=r'wikitable sortable collapsible mw-collapsible mw-made-collapsible jquery-tablesorter')
print(table)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWATv.png)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when you scrape the data from websites, the class of the elements changes or some class names disappear. Also, you need to write the class name in the form of a dictionary. So you need to write this code in order to get the required table:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217')
source = link.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable collapsible'})
print(table.prettify())
```

I think this will resolve your issue.

Comment: No luck, this receiving a None response.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns five tables on my machine. Note the use of a CSS selector.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

resp = requests.get(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217',
                    headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
# print(resp.status_code, resp.reason)
source = resp.content
soup = bs(source, 'html.parser')

selector = 'table.wikitable.sortable.collapsible'

for table in soup.select(selector):
    print(table)
```